# deducing operator() with std::invoke

Tags: c++17

I'm wondering why `std::invoke` cannot infer that `X` below has an operator with signature below vs. having the requirement to specify the pointer to member function explicitly. The latter makes `std::invoke` more generally applicable but are there rules that would prevent the special case from being deduced.

```
#include <functional>
struct X {
    void operator()() {         
    }
};

void call(X *ptr) {
//    std::invoke(ptr); // Does not compile
    std::invoke(&X::operator(), ptr); // Works
}
```